# "RPC Server Unavailable" when pushing a SCOM 2012 R2 agent from the console

Tags: system-center, scom

I'm attempting to push a SCOM 2012 R2 agent from the console to a Windows 7 desktop.  I've:

- Confirmed the firewall is disabled
- Confirmed I can ping it
- Confirmed the DNS name is correct both A/PTR
- Confirmed I can manage it through Computer Management (RPC test)
- Rebuilt the WMI repository and reregistered MOF files and rebooted
- Ensured the Windows Installer, Remote Registry, WMI and NetLogon services are started
- Am pushing with a management action account that's a domain admin and domain admins is a local administrator

I'm out of options for things to try.  I'd rather not install this manually.  I've deployed the agents to dozens of other Windows 7 machines.  There's just a select few that are giving me problems like this.